# IoT project, How to get a andorid notification when a value is UPDATED in the realtime databe?

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, push-notification

i'm doing a IoT project where i send data from 7 diferent NodeMCU sensor nodes, to a **FIREBASE Real-time Database**. I'm using a **Android APP as a HMI**, where the user can READ and WRITE in the database using the APP.

The thing that i'm trying to do is, when a value is UPDATED in the database by one of the nodes, the user recive a notification, ether the user is in or out the APP. I've sen a ton of tutorials where the user WRITE in the database using the APP, and then recibe de notifaction of what he write, here the nodes UPDATE the value and the APP notifies the user tha a value have been updated.

**Thigs i'v tried.**

Cloud functions, i'v set up a onUpdate typescript function, but i don't get as far as showing the change in the console log.

I'll show you my firebase structure.

[image]

As you can see, the value that is updated by the nodes is a true or false, and i need that when ACT/IN1 is updated to true, the user recive a notification.

Hope a made myself clear enough so you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger this from your Cloud Functions with an OnTrigger event.

```js
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/datos/ACT/{item}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.val();
      const oldValue = change.before.val();
      // Send FCM here
    });
```

From there, you can use logic to determine if you want to send a notification.

```js
const message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  token: registrationToken
};

// Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
// registration token.
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

You just need to find or store the registration token from the device to know where to send the notification which can be found per the documentation

- [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register)
- [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#access_the_registration_token)

Comment: Hi, i don't have enough REP to upvote, it works perfectly, appreciate your help a lot.